# Why add Adon Olam and Yigdal Elokim at the end of Shabbat Tefila

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, nusach-sefard

Many communities sing Adon Olam and Yigdal Elokim at the end of the Shabbat Tefila evening and morning. What is the source for this minhag and why are these particular songs are added?

On Shabbat morning I have never heard Yigdal Elokim, why? So why in the evening we can choose between the two and not always Yigdal in the evening and Adon Olam in the morning?